# query hbase like normal sql

Tags: sql, hadoop, hbase

I know `Hbase` is not like normal `SQL`.

But is it possible to query Hbase something like this?

```
 select row-key from Table 
 where cf:first="ram" and cf:middle="leela" and cf:last="ban";

 // ram(first name) leela(middle name) ban(last name)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two ways of doing it:

1. Use [Apache Phoenix](http://phoenix.apache.org) (**Recommended**). It's a powerful SQL wrapper for HBase.
2. Use Apache Hive. Hive can create an 'external table' using HiveQL:

```sql
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE employees (
    empid int,
    ename String
)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
COLLECTION ITEMS TERMINATED BY '#'
STORED BY 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.hbase.HBaseStorageHandler'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ("hbase.columns.mapping" = ":key,cf:ename")
TBLPROPERTIES ("hbase.table.name" = "employees");
```

Comment: Could you please explain why it's recommended? Thanks.

Comment: @jbmusso Apache Phoenix converts your SQL queries into HBase-native scans enabling you to build low-latency applications on top of HBase. Apache Hive, on the other hand, converts your queries into Hadoop map reduce jobs, which serve data warehousing purpose.